# distance function using the Frobenius norm on $R^{m \times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider
\begin{equation} d(A,B) = \frac{\|A - B \|_{\text{F}}}{\frac{1}{2} \cdot (\|A\|_{\text{F}} + \|B\|_{\text{F}})} \end{equation}
with $\| \ \cdot \|_{\text{F}}$ the Frobenius norm, and $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ matrices of the same size. Does $d(A,B)$ form a metric on the space $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$? And say that the matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is fixed, do we have that
\begin{equation} n( \ \cdot | B) = d( \ \cdot \ , B) : \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
forms a norm on the space $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$?

I suspect that $n(\cdot | B)$ does not form a norm due to $n(2 \cdot A | B)$ in general not being equal to $2 \cdot n(A | B)$.

Thank you in advance if you have any ideas on both questions,
greetings

Comment: What are your ideas on the problem? [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959)

Comment: I suspect that n(\cdot | B) does not form a norm due to $n(2 \cdot A | B)$ in general not being equal to $2 \cdot n(A | B)$

Comment: @L.C. You should first ask yourself the question is $d(a,b) = \frac{\lvert a-b \rvert}{ \lvert a \rvert + \lvert b \rvert}$ a distance on the reals?

Comment: from this definition what is $d\big(\mathbf 0, \mathbf 0\big)$?

Comment: @user8675309 Ah yeah $d(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{0})$ is not defined. And what about the question whether $d(x,y)$ defines a metric on $ \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} $?

Comment: I mean on $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \setminus \{\mathbf{0}\}$